# boto3 copy_object with AES256

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a cross account bucket and I am trying to copy a file from one folder to another in the same bucket. The bucket has SSE-S3 with AES256 encryption. I am able to copy the file using the CLI however the python code doesn't throws an AccessDenied exception during the CopyObject. Any ideas as to what could be going wrong?

Here is the cli command that succeeds. I have already done the assume role from the CLI before doing this.

```
aws s3 cp s3://some-bucket/out/out-files/sample_file.parquet s3://some-bucket/in/in-logs/ --sse
```

python code follows

```
sts_client = boto3.client('sts')
assumed_role_object = sts_client.assume_role(RoleArn=role_arn, RoleSessionName="AssumeRoleSession")
credentials=assumed_role_object['Credentials']
s3_client=boto3.client('s3', region_name=region_name, aws_access_key_id=credentials['AccessKeyId'], aws_secret_access_key=credentials['SecretAccessKey'],aws_session_token=credentials['SessionToken'])
    
copy_source = {'Bucket': bucket_name, 'Key': oldKey}
s3_client.copy_object(Bucket=bucket_name, CopySource=copy_source, Key=newKey, ServerSideEncryption='AES256')
```

Exception is:

> botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the CopyObject operation: Access Denied

Comment: Where are you running those commands? If the AWS CLI is being used on an Amazon EC2 instance, it will obtain credentials from the IAM Role that is assigned to the instance. If it is running on your own computer, it will obtain credentials from the `~/.aws/credentials` file. Why is your Python code calling `AssumeRole()` -- does that mean it is using different credentials from the AWS CLI? The error message you are receiving suggests that the AWS CLI is using different credentials from the assumed role.

Comment: What is a "cross account bucket"? Are you saying that the bucket being accessed is in a different AWS Account than the credentials being used to run the commands? If so, how are those credentials being given permission to access the bucket?